# ionic cordova build browser not minifying anymore

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, browser

I have used the above command to minify and optimize my files, but lately it has stopped minifying my code

Has anyone else experienced this?

my version info is:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.3
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 8.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add optional flags to `ionic cordova build browser [flags]`

For example: `ionic cordova build browser --prod`, will perform a production build for your Ionic application. This includes minify, uglify, ...

Full documentation onto this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/#details

**Note:** Chrome/Firefox/... Debug tools use so called **source maps** to rebuild your minified, combined files. So it may look like the files are not minifed while they are.

Comment: thanks, but I was looking to get the command working like before

Comment: It is the exact same command with flags, I would recommend to use it anyways

Comment: I misunderstood you - I do always use the flags, but I was not getting the expected results even with them?!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reinstall Cordova (the program files had been moved)

npm install -g cordova-cli

npm install -D cordova

Now my ionic info includes Cordova global v8